# Subset of table driven test

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go, tdd

For testing functions I could select which will run by option `-run`.

```
go test -run regex
```

Very common if we have dozens test cases is put it into array in order not to write function for each of that:

```
cases := []struct {
  arg, expected string
} {
    {"%a", "[%a]"},
    {"%-a", "[%-a]"},
    // and many others
}
for _, c := range cases {
  res := myfn(c.arg) 
  if  res != c.expected {
    t.Errorf("myfn(%q) should return %q, but it returns %q", c.arg, c.expected, res)
  }
}
```

This work good, but problem is with maintanance. When I add a new testcase, while debugging I want to start just a new test case, but I cannot say something like:

```
go test -run TestMyFn.onlyThirdCase
```

Is there any elegant way, how to have many testcases in array together with ability to choose which testcase will run?

Comment: Just wait a few days for Go 1.7 :-)

Comment: @Volker Good point, incorporated.

Answer (score 4):

### With Go 1.6 (and below)

This is not supported directly by the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package in Go 1.6 and below. You have to implement it yourself.

But it's not that hard. You can use [`flag`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) package to easily access command line arguments.

Let's see an example. We define an `"idx"` command line parameter, which if present, only the case at that index will be executed, else all test cases.

Define flag:

```
var idx = flag.Int("idx", -1, "specify case index to run only")
```

Parse command line flags (actually, this is not required as `go test` already calls this, but just to be sure / complete):

```
func init() {
    flag.Parse()
}
```

Using this parameter:

```
for i, c := range cases {
    if *idx != -1 && *idx != i {
        println("Skipping idx", i)
        continue
    }
    if res := myfn(c.arg); res != c.expected {
        t.Errorf("myfn(%q) should return %q, but it returns %q", c.arg, c.expected, res)
    }
}
```

Testing it with 3 test cases:

```
cases := []struct {
    arg, expected string
}{
    {"%a", "[%a]"},
    {"%-a", "[%-a]"},
    {"%+a", "[%+a]"},
}
```

Without `idx` parameter:

```
go test
```

Output:

```
PASS
ok      play    0.172s
```

Specifying an index:

```
go test -idx=1
```

Output:

```
Skipping idx 0
Skipping idx 2
PASS
ok      play    0.203s
```

Of course you can implement more sophisticated filtering logic, e.g. you can have `minidx` and `maxidx` flags to run cases in a range:

```
var (
    minidx = flag.Int("minidx", 0, "min case idx to run")
    maxidx = flag.Int("maxidx", -1, "max case idx to run")
)
```

And the filtering:

```
if i < *minidx || *maxidx != -1 && i > *maxidx {
    println("Skipping idx", i)
    continue
}
```

Using it:

```
go test -maxidx=1
```

Output:

```
Skipping idx 2
PASS
ok      play    0.188s
```

### Starting with Go 1.7

Go 1.7 (to be released on August 18, 2016) adds the definition of [subtests and sub-benchmarks](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.7#testing):

> The testing package now supports the definition of tests with subtests and benchmarks with sub-benchmarks. This support makes it easy to write table-driven benchmarks and to create hierarchical tests. It also provides a way to share common setup and tear-down code. See the [package documentation](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Subtests_and_Sub_benchmarks) for details.

With that, you can do things like:

```
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    // <setup code>
    t.Run("A=1", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    t.Run("A=2", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    t.Run("B=1", func(t *testing.T) { ... })
    // <tear-down code>
}
```

Where the subtests are named `"A=1"`, `"A=2"`, `"B=1"`.

> The argument to the -run and -bench command-line flags is a slash-separated list of regular expressions that match each name element in turn. For example:
>
> ```
> go test -run Foo     # Run top-level tests matching "Foo".
> go test -run Foo/A=  # Run subtests of Foo matching "A=".
> go test -run /A=1    # Run all subtests of a top-level test matching "A=1".
> ```

How does this help your case? The names of subtests are `string` values, which can be generated on-the-fly, e.g.:

```
for i, c := range cases {
    name := fmt.Sprintf("C=%d", i)
    t.Run(name, func(t *testing.T) {
        if res := myfn(c.arg); res != c.expected {
            t.Errorf("myfn(%q) should return %q, but it returns %q",
                c.arg, c.expected, res)
        }
    })
}
```

To run the case at index `2`, you could start it like

```
go test -run /C=2
```

or

```
go test -run TestName/C=2
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple code, that work fine with both, although with a bit different command line options. Version for 1.7 is:

```
// +build go1.7

package plist

import "testing"

func runTest(name string, fn func(t *testing.T), t *testing.T) {
    t.Run(name, fn)
}
```

and 1.6 and older:

```
// +build !go1.7

package plist

import (
    "flag"
    "testing"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
)

func init() {
    flag.Parse()
}

var pattern = flag.String("pattern", "", "specify which test(s) should be executed")
var verbose = flag.Bool("verbose", false, "write whether test was done")

// This is a hack, that a bit simulate t.Run available from go1.7
func runTest(name string, fn func(t *testing.T), t *testing.T) {
    // obtain name of caller
    var pc[10]uintptr
    runtime.Callers(2, pc[:])
    var fnName = ""

    f := runtime.FuncForPC(pc[0])
    if f != nil {
        fnName = f.Name()
    }
    names := strings.Split(fnName, ".")
    fnName = names[len(names)-1] + "/" + name
    if strings.Contains(fnName, *pattern) {
        if *verbose {
            fmt.Printf("%s is executed\n", fnName)
        }
        fn(t)
    } else {
        if *verbose {
            fmt.Printf("%s is skipped\n", fnName)
        }
    }
}
```